# How to add translate in file master.html in pagebuilder in magento 2

Tags: magento2, translate, page-builder

Like in the title - I have a problem with adding translate to file master.html in PageBuilder.
I tried these solutions:

```
 <h3 data-bind="i18n: 'text'"></h3>
 <h3 translate="'text'"></h3>
```

And it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use:

```
 {{trans "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to add translation functionality to the master.html file in Magento 2 Page Builder:

1. Create a language file for your theme first. To accomplish this,
   create a new directory in
   app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/i18n and name it en US for
   English US.
2. Next, in the i18n directory, create a new CSV file and name it after
   your theme (e.g. YourTheme.csv). Your translations will be saved in
   this file.
3. Open Page Builder and locate the text that needs to be translated in
   the master.html file.
4. Wrap the text in the __() function, as in: __("Your text here").
5. Save the master.html file.
6. Open the YourTheme.csv file and create a new row for each text
   string to be translated. The text string (in English) should be in
   the first column, and the translated text string should be in the
   second.
7. Save the file YourTheme.csv.
8. Flush the Magento cache.

When you view your store in the translated language, the text that you wrapped in the __() function should now be displayed in the translated language.

Comment: It doesn't works